# Редактор на jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

**Имеется:** [редактор на jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/sPFeW/9/)

**Требуется:** чтобы при выборе цвета A, курсор при зажатой клавише перекрашивал ячейки в цвет А. При выборе цвета B аналогично, и так далее.

**Проблема:** 
при выборе зеленого, рисует зеленым 
переключаемся на коричневый, рисует зеленым,
переключаемся на синий, рисует синим
далее что бы не делать рисует синим

**Вопрос:** В чем ошибка в моем коде? И как его можно оптимизировать? Так как у меня смутные сомнения что я сотворил что то на грани паники и хаоса.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> В чем ошибка в моем коде?

ошибка в том, что вы не удаляете установленные классы, и получается вот такая ситуация:

```
<div class="ground tree water"></div>
```

класс `water` перекрывает все остальные, не уверен, но наверно потому что он идёт последним по алфавиту

> И как его можно оптимизировать?

**да его переделывать полностью!** хотя это моё субъективное мнение, но всякие канвасы и SVG для этой цели лучше, чем таблица

Comment: Спасибо. Строка
    $(this).removeClass().addClass("ABC");
помогла.
А на счет все переписать, думаю как освоюсь в jquery и js в целом, вернусь к этому вопросу. А это мой первый рабочий код.